# Enable/Disable button according with the data values

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application, in the index view I want to show and hide some buttons according with their values. Need a help of doing that operation from you all.

This is my Index view.

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
        <table id="MyRequest" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 1%">
                        Request Number
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Request Type
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Created Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                          Request Heading
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Request Timeline
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReqestTypeDisplay)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created_Date)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Req_Heading)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReqestApprovalStatus)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary pull-right" })
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning pull-right" })
                            @Html.ActionLink("Approval", "Index", "ReportsViewModel", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success pull-right" })
                            @Html.ActionLink( "Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id },new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');", @class = "btn btn-danger pull-right" })
                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[HTML view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs0La.png)

There are values in the **RequestApprovalStatus** Column.  I want to enable the edit button only the Approval Status value equals to **At Department head** . Otherwise I want to disable the edit button also Approval Button only can be enable if Approval Status equals to **Approved** Only. Can some one help me with this about how to do this. Can this done using jQuery ?

Comment: Maybe something like this would work.  class for your edit "button" `new { @class = "btn btn-primary pull-right" + (item.ReqestApprovalStatus == "At Department head" ? "disabled":"") }`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Thanks. This method also working. and insted of value "disabled" I replaced "btn-primary disabled" Then it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to do what you ask using client-side JS, if you have access to the data on the server side (as your example shows) then the better way ***by far*** is to disable the button on the server side.

Given that the 'buttons' are actually anchor elements, disabling them is not so simple as adding the `disabled` attribute. However, from the names of the classes applied to the elements it appears you're using Bootstrap. As such, you can add the `disabled` class to the links and the Bootstrap library will prevent the links being clicked for you.

With that said, try this:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id))
{
  var editClass = item.RequestApprovalStatus == "At Department head" ? "" : "disabled";
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReqestTypeDisplay)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Created_Date)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Req_Heading)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReqestApprovalStatus)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = $"btn btn-primary pull-right " + editClass })
      @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning pull-right" })
      @Html.ActionLink("Approval", "Index", "ReportsViewModel", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success pull-right" })
      @Html.ActionLink( "Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id },new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');", @class = "btn btn-danger pull-right" })
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This method also working. and insted of value "disabled" I replaced "btn-primary disabled" Then it worked. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help